# React Native How to reduce minSdkVersion = 21 to 19?

Tags: react-native

Last version React Native supports only Android 5.0 (API 21) or newer. How can I decrease that to 19 (Android 4.4), even if I have to use old versions RN?

Comment: Use a previous RN version?

Comment: But which one would fit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [Changelog](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md), you can see that in version 0.64:

```
v0.64.0
Breaking
Enable inlineRequires by default in new projects' metro.config.js. Gives a performance benefit but slightly different JS execution order (959365a902 by @GantMan)
Minimum supported Node version changed to 12 (4b92e2e53d by @safaiyeh)
Remove deprecated CameraRoll API (deprecated in 0.61) (824d3a9770 by @seanyusa)
Remove deprecated CheckBox component (deprecated in 0.60) (dff17effe5 by @poteto)
Removed DEPRECATED_sendUpdatedChildFrames prop from ScrollView component (deprecated in 0.47) (345d0c1abb by @ZHUANGPP)
On Image, onLoad event objects' source.url is now renamed to source.uri. (74ab8f6e5a by @yungsters)

**Android specific**
**Remove support of Android API levels 16 through 20. The new minSDK version will be 21+ moving forward.** (973198667d, 25a40cbc61, f829722b54, b133427778, 9b34aa261c, and 79d0a7d711 by @mdvacca; 49f10fd2e5 and a17ff44adc by @JoshuaGross; dd4298a377 by @safaiyeh)
Fix ReadableArray null annotations. Possibly breaking change for Kotlin apps. (d76556543f by @dulmandakh)
On Image, onLoad and onError event objects will no longer have an extra uri property. (74ab8f6e5a by @yungsters)
Deletes the method PlayTouchSound method from UIManagerModule, this method was moved to the SoundManagerModule class. (d0c4c5eaf9 by @mdvacca)
```

So you can use ***0.63***.